# Git workflow for web development test deployment

Tags: php, git, github, workflow, web-deployment

We are a very small team of 4 people working on the same web development project.

We are using github for version control and are currently creating a new branch for each feature we are working on, then merging it back to 'development.'

As of now we don't have a graceful way to test our own branches on our test server. Currently we are using various syncing scripts to copy our branch to the server.

On our server we have a directory for each feature like so:

```
/feature_a
/feature_b
/feature_c
/development
```

Is there a way to utilize git on the server to auto create these folders for each branch and keep them updated with what we push?

Note: The server is Windows and we are developing on Macs